# ¿Cómo hago para generar la carpeta site de Jacoco en Java?

Tags: java, java-8, test, junit

Estoy intentando generar la carpeta site de JaCoCo para poder ver la cobertura de mi código, he probado varios tipos de comandos:

```
mvn clean install
mvn test
mvn verify
mvn site
```

Adjunto el plugin de mi pom.xml (la versión que le estoy agregando es la 0.8.3 desde otro fichero)

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>com/ing/treasury/swift/**/*</include>
                    </includes>
                    <!--Excludes in IntelliJ Code Coverage View show them with 0%-->
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>Aqui tengo exclusiones</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <destFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
                    <dataFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-site</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

*Aquí sigue sin generarse la carpeta site*
[image: Ficheros en target]

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza esta configuración y los plugins siguientes,tienes que tomar en cuenta que el profile se coloca en la raiz del pom

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0.1398</version>
        </plugin>
        <!--Maven Surefire Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </plugin>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>coverage</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>prepare-agent</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>report</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                            
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```